# how to hide attachment of inline image in java

Tags: java

This is a part of setting inline image in java here setting the content id.

```
   MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    imagePart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<" + contentId + ">");
                    imagePart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
    this part is to concentrate 
                    String imageFilePath = mapInlineImages.get(contentId);
                    try {
```

Here attaching file how to hide it.

```
                   //imagePart.attachFile(imageFilePath);
                        DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(imageFilePath);
                        imagePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  mimemultipart.addBodyPart(imagePart);
```

Comment: Can you make your question more clear?

Comment: this code helps to implement inline image in email but also showing an attachment in email .i want to hide or disable that on email through codes .how?

Comment: More specifically ,i want to send an email with inline image in java  and without any attachment of that image.

Answer (score 0):

You can not.

But you can use a `img`-tag having a `href` to a official image location.

Example:

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/image.png" />
```

If you do not send the image as an attachment the mail is getting smaller, no attachment-sign is set and you do not litter the postbox-space of the recipient.